# Find the area of the triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

There are two points $N$ and $M$ on the sides $AB$ and $BC$ of the triangle $ABC$ respectively. The lines $AM$ and $CN$ intersect at point $P$. Find the area of the triangle $ABC$, if areas of triangles $ANP, CMP, CPA$ are $6,8,7$ respectively.

Comment: I tried to use Heron's formula, in order to find at least the length of one side, but it wasn't successful. I need just an idea how can I do that in order to come to a proper solution way.

Comment: Next time, please provide that (very important) piece of information. Also, it helps if you can provide some context (scope of the problem for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

From the hypothesis, it follows that

1. $CN:CP = area(\triangle CAN):area(\triangle CPA)=13:7$
2. $MP:MA =area(\triangle CMP):area(\triangle CMA)=8:15$

Applying [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus'_theorem) to $\triangle APN$ with $B, M,C$ we have that
$$\frac{BN}{BA}\cdot \frac{CN}{CP}\cdot \frac{MP}{MA}=1,\tag{3}$$
(note that we use non-directed length here). So
$$\frac{area(\triangle ABC)}{area(\triangle BCN)}=\frac{BA}{BN}=\frac{CP}{CN}\cdot \frac{MA}{MP}=\frac{7}{13}\cdot\frac{15}{8}=\frac{105}{104}.$$
It follows that $$area(\triangle ABC)=105\times area(\triangle ACN)=\color{red}{1365}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be area (CAN): area(CPA) ?

Comment: @nlimits  Yes, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$
\begin{cases}
a &= \verb/Area/(ANP) = 6\\
b &= \verb/Area/(CPA) = 7\\
c &= \verb/Area/(CMP) = 8
\end{cases}$$

and $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ be the [barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of $P$ with respect to $\triangle ABC$. i.e
the triplet of numbers such that

$$\vec{P} = \alpha \vec{A} + \beta \vec{B} + \gamma \vec{C}\quad\text{ subject to }\quad \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$$

Following is a picture illustrating the arrangement of points and labeling
(not drawn to scale because the actual triangle is highly acute and
hard to display)

$\hspace1in$ [image: A triangle torn into 4 pieces]

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac{\verb/Area/(CMP)}{\verb/Area/(CMA)} = \frac{c}{c+b}\\
\gamma &= \frac{\verb/Area/(ANP)}{\verb/Area/(ANC)} = \frac{a}{a+b}\\
\end{align}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{\verb/Area/(CPA)}{\verb/Area/(ABC)} = \beta = 1 - \alpha - \gamma
$$
This leads to $$\verb/Area/(ABC) = \frac{\verb/Area/(CPA)}{1 - \frac{c}{c+b} - \frac{a}{a+b}}
= \frac{b}{1 -\frac{c}{c+b} - \frac{a}{a+b}}
= \frac{b(a+b)(c+b)}{b^2-ac}\\ = \frac{7(6+7)(7+8)}{7^2-6\cdot 8} = 1365$$

Comment: You could enlarge the basis and diminish the height of the triangle so that it is not highly acute. In what sense do you plan to use affine maps to do this? What advantage do you get by performing such transformation?

Comment: @BeniBogosel if you do that, $P$ will be very close to $AC$ and hard to see the three triangles $ANP$, $CMP$ and $CPA$.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: Now that I've seen the actual solution in my answer, the situation becomes clearer to me. I now understand how the triangle has to be very acute (small angle at point $B$) *if* the lines $AM$ and $CN$ are to intersect in such a way that they are easy to distinguish. I'm violating the latter in my drawing, and achille probably had that condition in his mind implicitely. In any case, I now agree that the situation is hard to depict to scale, even though I did so. Deleted my original comment since it no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Geometry Approach

Note that, with the same altitude, ratio of areas of two triangles is equal to the ratio of their bases.

[image]

Therefore, $\dfrac {x}{y} = \dfrac {NP}{PC} = \dfrac {u}{v + z}$ ….. (*)

Similarly, $\dfrac {z}{y} = \dfrac {v}{u + x}$ ….. (#)

After eliminating v from (*) and (#) and making u as subject, we have

$ u = \dfrac {xyz +x^2z}{y^2 - xz}$

Similarly, or by symmetry, we have $v = \dfrac {xyz +z^2x}{y^2 - xz}$

∴ $[\triangle ABC] = x + y + z + u + v = x + y + z + \dfrac {xyz +x^2z}{y^2 - xz} + \dfrac {xyz +z^2x}{y^2 - xz} = ... = 1365$.

Answer (score 0):

While the other approaches (using Menelaos' theorem or barycentric coordinates) are very elegant, here is one which might work if you can't think of all the clever geometric theorems needed for those.

## Coordinate-based approach

Since all you talk about is areas, the whole setup is invariant under area-preserving affine transformations. Therefore you may without loss of generality assume that your triangle has a right angle at $B$, and choose your coordinate system such that you have

$$B=(0,0)\quad C=(c,0)\quad A=(0,a)\quad M=(m,0)\quad N=(0,n)$$

[image: Sketch]

Here $c,a,m,n$ are the distance of the corresponding upper-case points from $B$. So you have four unknowns and three equations, which in general doesn't lead to a unique solution. But that's because we still haven't fully determined the shape of the triangle, since we could vary it's aspect ratio while preserving its areas. So again without loss of generality, let's assume that $P=(p,p)$ lies on the line $x=y$. Now let's formulate the equations. The lines $AM$ and $CN$ have equations

$$
AM: ax + my = am \qquad CN: nx + cy = cn
$$

so if $P$ is to lie on both of them, you have

\begin{align*}
ap + mp &= am \\
np + cp &= cn \\
\tfrac12\cdot p\cdot(a-n) &= 6 = \operatorname{area}(ANP) \\
\tfrac12\cdot(c-m)\cdot p &= 8 = \operatorname{area}(CMP) \\
\tfrac12\cdot(ac-ap-pc) &= 7 = \operatorname{area}(CPA)
\end{align*}

That system of equations has [two real solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7Ba*p%2Bm*p%3Da*m%2C%20n*p%2Bc*p%3Dc*n%2C%20p*%28a-n%29%3D12%2C%20p*%28c-m%29%3D16%2C%20a*c-a*p-p*c%3D14%7D), which only differ by a global change of all signs (i.e. by a rotation around the origin by $180°$). One of them is

\begin{align*}
a &= 15\sqrt{\frac{21}{2}} & a \approx 48.60555523805895 \\
c &= 26\sqrt{\frac{14}{3}} & c \approx 56.16641938620146 \\
m &= 60\sqrt{\frac{6}{7}} & m \approx 55.54920598635309 \\
n &= 52\sqrt{\frac{6}{7}} & n \approx 48.14264518817268 \\
p &= 4\sqrt{42} & p \approx 25.92296279363144
\end{align*}

$$ \operatorname{area}(ABC) = \tfrac12ac = 1365 $$

So in reality, your triangle looks more like this:

[image: Actual solution]

## The role of orientation

But perhaps the question was meant in a different way. Perhaps $M$ and $N$ need not lie on the line *segment* between the corresponding triangle corners, but may lie anywhere on the infinite extension of that edge. Perhaps there is a reason why $ANP$ is oriented counter-clockwise in my first diagram but $CMP$ and $CPA$ are oriented clockwise. If I switch the sign of $CMP$ and $CPA$ (since counter-clockwise is usually considered the positive orientation) I get a different pair of solutions, which look like this:

[image: Solution with orientations]

Here $ANP, CMP, CPA$ are all oriented counter-clockwise. Here $\operatorname{area}(ABC)=-\frac{105}{97}$ which is negative since the triangle is oriented clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

We may assume $P=(0,0)$, $A=(0,a)$, $C=(c,0)$, $N=(-v,0)$, and $M=(0,-u)$. The given information amounts to
$$ac=14,\qquad u={16\over c},\qquad v={12\over a}\ ;\tag{1}$$
furthermore the $x$-coordinate of $B=(C\vee M)\wedge(A\vee N)$ computes to
$$x_B=-{vc(a+u)\over ac-uv}\ .$$
The area of the triangle $\triangle:=\triangle(A,B,C)$ is then given by
$$|\triangle|={1\over2}(a+u)(c-x)={1\over2}{(a+u)(c+v)ac\over ac-uv}\ .$$
Using $(1)$ we get
$$|\triangle|={1\over2}\>{(ac+16)(ac+12)\over ac-{192\over ac}}=1365\ .$$